# PostgreSQL | Combine queries results

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a "simple" situation here, but I couldn't resolve it by myself. So what I need is combine one result from the first query with the second one, to get a "final result".

The first query get the number of shots by player.

```
SELECT player, COUNT(shot) shots FROM table1 GROUP BY player;
```

> ```
> +---------+-------+
> | player  | shots |
> +---------+-------+
> | player1 | 10    |
> +---------+-------+
> | player2 | 10    |
> +---------+-------+
> ```

The second is to get the hits.

```
SELECT player, COUNT(hit) hits FROM table2 GROUP BY player;
```

> ```
> +---------+-------+
> | player  | hits  |
> +---------+-------+
> | player1 | 10    |
> +---------+-------+
> | player2 | 5     |
> +---------+-------+
> ```

And what I need is to calculate the accuracy (hits / shots * 100), displaying the result something like that.

> ```
> +---------+-------+------+-----+
> | player  | shots | hits | acc |
> +---------+-------+------+-----+
> | player1 | 10    | 10   | 100 |
> +---------+-------+------+-----+
> | player2 | 10    | 5    | 50  |
> +---------+-------+------+-----+
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `join` after aggregation:

```
SELECT player, s.shots, h.hits
FROM (SELECT player, COUNT(shot) as shots
      FROM table1
      GROUP BY player
     ) s JOIN
     (SELECT player, COUNT(hit) as hits
      FROM table2
      GROUP BY player
     ) h
     USING (player);
```

Do you really intend `COUNT()`?  It seems that `SUM()` would be more appropriate.

Also, this only returns players in both tables.  If you want players in either table, use `FULL JOIN`.

Comment: Thx! This solution works for me. I have to use ```COUNT()``` because it's kind of log table, so each line counts as shot or hit.